Best modelling method when target is a distribution
I have a regression task where each data sample is annotated by multiple (5-10) experts. I observe that the annotated target of each data sample is a Gaussian distribution.
Usually, people will use the mean as the target and treat it as an ordinary regression task but I want the model to also predict the variance for uncertainty quantification.
How should I design a model to learn from both the mean and variance of the Gaussian distribution?
I am thinking of a simple neural network with 2 outputs and learn the mean and variance directly with MSE loss.
Edit:
The data looks something like this:

input: face images
target: age of the person, but instead of having only one ground truth to train on, I have multiple "ground truth" from different experts for the same image


Please be more precise about your data format. What is your target? How does it look? What have the experts to do with all this?

What I would do is if the experts are the same in all rows, I would create a model for every expert. Then I will get a prediction for every model so then I will be able to compute the mean and the variance of these predictions.

@BillyBonaros Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this for a toy dataset. However, training and inference time would also scale with the number of experts.

[after your edits of the question this answer does not fit anymore]
This sounds as if all that you need to do is to fit a Gaussian distribution to your (training) data. For this, you can simple use numpy/scipy, as e.g., in this example:
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create some training data
ng = np.random.default_rng()
mean, std = 1, 0.5
x = norm.rvs(mean, std, size=1000, random_state=rng)

# show the data
plt.hist(x, bins=50)
plt.show()

# train the model
model_mean, model_std = norm.fit(x)
print(model_mean, model_std)
```

